# How to copy formatted text with <RenderHtml/>

Tags: react-native-render-html

I have a copy function to copy the text programmatically but I wanted to copy the formatted text, not the raw HTML. Is there a way to access the formatted text?

```
<RenderHtml
            contentWidth={width}
            source={{ html: item.content }}
            defaultTextProps={{ selectable: true }}
/>
```